# android studio can't generate new apk file

Tags: android, android-studio

android studio can't generate new apk file :

[image: Screenshot]

> failed to complete gradle execution

cause :

> a fatal exeption has occured !

Comment: Have you tried restart Android Studio? Or restart computer? I have faced with similar problem

Comment: the problem is solved, thanks